# Python read from txt to csv with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, io

I got text file and my text file includes infos about department and managers
Example part from txt :

```
department: sale
group : building a 
manager::sergey

department: hr 
group : building a 
manager::tom 
location:somewhereelse

department: health
group : building b 
manager::jeniffer 
manager::billy

department: security 
group : building b 
manager::john
```

Between every department there is one empty line after manager name/names. and one space after every info at lines.

Im using df_readcsv and transform that csv for making columns with dep, group , manager,location

There are 2 problems

1- Sometimes there can be 2 manager at dep(like health department) . If there are 2 managers at same department I failed. My code works only for 1 manager. How can add one more column with other manager?

2- Sometimes there are more rows than other rows look at hr department. There is info about location. It makes harder to doing regular df. 
It needs dynamic structure I suppose :(

Example of What It should be

```
dep           group             manager     Location
sale          building a        sergey      ""
hr            building a        tom          somewhereelse
health        building b        jeniffer     ""
health        building b        billy         ""
```

What can I do ?

My code

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', sep="\n")
df = data.replace({ '# department: ' : " ", '# group:' : " ",'# manager:' : " ",}, regex= True)
ab = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 7), 
                    columns=["department","group","manager"])
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I posted my code as you wish.

Comment: @DelimeterAwr: is the name of the department unique throughout a file?

Comment: And one more question: how long is your file?

Comment: not bigger than 5 mb for now.

Comment: yes unique but sometimes some entrieslike department/xx , department//yy but they are unique also what I mean department/xx != department//yy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# read the file in the structure it is
# using a consequtive series of : as 
# field separators
# and cutting off the spaces before
# and after the colon
# the two fields are named _key and _value
# skip the blank lines
df= pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO(raw), 
        sep='\s*:+\s*', 
        skip_blank_lines=True,
        names=['_key', '_value'],
        engine='python')

# now build groups to identify which
# rows belong together
# assuming each group begins with
# a line containing department in the
# key column
group_ser= df['_key'] == 'department'
df['_group']= group_ser.cumsum()

# now get rid of the duplicate manager
# rows by putting the manager values
# into a list
df_agg_managers= df[df['_key']=='manager'].groupby(['_group', '_key']).agg({'_value':list})

# the rest actually does not deed to be
# aggregated according to your description
# so just add the index structure so it
# matches the one of df_agg_managers
df_rest=         df[df['_key']!='manager'].set_index(['_group', '_key'])
df_all= pd.concat([df_agg_managers, df_rest], axis='index')

# now use the content of the _key column
# to build columns (like in a pivot operation)
df_unstacked= df_all.unstack()
# get rid of the first level in the column names
df_unstacked.columns= df_unstacked.columns.get_level_values(1)

# count the number of entries per manager
# column
len_ser= df_unstacked['manager'].map(len)
# below we loop only over the rows that contain
# lists with at least one element, so we need
# an extra treatment for the rows with empty
# lists or NaN
df_result= df_unstacked.loc[(len_ser<1) | df_unstacked['manager'].isna()].reset_index()
# now create one row per entry in the manager-list
for i in range(len_ser.max()):
    df_work= df_unstacked.loc[len_ser > i].copy()
    df_work['manager']= df_work['manager'].map(lambda lst: lst[i])
    df_result= pd.concat([df_result, df_work.reset_index()], axis='index', ignore_index=True)

# apply some final cosmetics
# sort the rows so they appear groupwise
# then remove the _group column
df_result.sort_values('_group').drop(['_group'], axis='columns')
```

The result is:

```
_key department       group       location   manager
0          sale  building a            NaN    sergey
1            hr  building a  somewhereelse       tom
2        health  building b            NaN  jeniffer
4        health  building b            NaN     billy
3      security  building b            NaN      john
```

If run on the following test data:

```
raw="""department: sale
group : building a 
manager::sergey

department: hr 
group : building a 
manager::tom 
location:somewhereelse

department: health
group : building b 
manager::jeniffer 
manager::billy

department: security 
group : building b 
manager::john"""
```

**Note:** in case the assumption is wrong that all groups begin with department, you can also use the blank lines to group your content. You could just replace the first few lines by:

```
df= pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO(raw), 
        sep='\s*:+\s*', 
        skip_blank_lines=False,
        names=['_key', '_value'],
        engine='python')

group_ser= df['_key'].isna()
df['_group']= group_ser.cumsum()+1
df.drop(group_ser[group_ser==True].index, axis='index', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hey sorry for my late reply. Firstly I wrote pathname /local/company.txt to raw at second line  then I run the code but

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-601bcac0c505> in <module>
     39 df_unstacked= df_all.unstack()

Comment: 40 # get rid of the first level in the column names
---> 41 df_unstacked.columns= df_unstacked.columns.get_level_values(1)
     42 
     43 # count the number of entries per manager

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5173             or name in self._accessors
   5174         ):
-> 5175             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5176         else:
   5177             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: It shows line 41 which is df_unstacked.columns= df_unstacked.columns.get_level_values(1)

Comment: I also add
import pandas as pd
import io
at beginning for io.stringio(/.txt)

Comment: Sorry, from what you write it is hard to say what went wrong. Somehow you got a series, where you should have gotten a dataframe. The above code works, so maybe you can check where you get a series. Maybe you used something like `df[colname]` somewhere instead of `df[[colname]]`?

Comment: I just doublechecked. Both are dataframes `df_agg_managers` as well as `df_rest`, so the concatenated result is also a dataframe. Please check if after your modification both parts are dataframes as well.

Comment: I pasted code and error for you : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/j7KwTyWNfj/

Comment: @DelimeterAwr: that's really odd, because the `unstack` is supposed to create columns, so `df_unstacked` should be a dataframe, not a series. Can you please check what structure `df_all` after line 35? Especially, if '_group' and '_key' are index columns and that '_key' contains the values 'group', 'manager' etc. Does the dataframe you read with `read_csv` contain the expected values?

Comment: You can also pass `squeeze=False` in the `groupby`. Like in `groupby(['_group', '_key'], squeeze=False)`. But according to the documentation that is the default anyways, so `groupby` should produce a `DataFrame`.

Comment: I finally also added my test data, which is the text you provided in your question. Maybe you can verify if it works unchange with your setup. If not, please try to add the `squeeze=False` argument. If it works, the data you read from the file probably has a slightly differnt format and maybe it helps to compare the output of the intermediate results.

Comment: I gave you point because of your effort but Is there anyway to doing this without pasting data in io .?

Comment: Thank you. Of course. The `io.StringIO` part above is just because I don't have your file and worked with the output, you gave in your question. Just replace `io.StringIO(raw)` by your file name and it should work.

Comment: I tried but :D can you tried with create .txt file and pasting the data which u used on .txt file and giving path of .txt file to string io ? :D I think ıt wont work :D

Comment: Insead of `df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw), sep='\s*:+\s*', skip_blank_lines=True, names=['_key', '_value'],       engine='python')` just write `df= pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep='\s*:+\s*', skip_blank_lines=True, names=['_key', '_value'],       engine='python')`. Just replace the string by your actual filename. Good luck.